# clapack.h or  Template Numerical Toolkit in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, lapack

I want to use the lapack library [clapck](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/index.html), but how could I use it in Visual Studio 2008, in a C++ project...

Also I was reviewing [Template Numerical Toolkit](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/download.html)

Have you done something similar, what do you recommend to use with Visual Studio C++ project?
Can you post a simple example with the headers that must be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TNT is easy enough.

    #include "cmat.h"
    #include "lu.h"
    /*******************************
     * PURPOSE: Solves a linear equation in the form of Ax = b.
     *****/
    using namespace TNT;
    void matrix_solve(double V[9], double xb[3])
    {
      Matrix<double> A(3, 3, V);
      Vector<int> ipiv(3);
      Vector<double> b(3, xb);
      LU_factor(A, ipiv);
      LU_solve(A, ipiv, b);
      xb[0] = b[0];
      xb[1] = b[1];
      xb[2] = b[2];
    }
```